# how to only print Lua output with tshark

Tags: lua, wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I am using a Lua script with tshark and when I run it with -V I get the protocol decode output. When I try anything else to limit output to just the Lua decoded data I am not having any luck. i.e.

```
tshark -X lua_script:my.lua -r input.pcap.gz -w output.pcap -O "my lua protocol" or tshark -X lua_script:my.lua -r input.pcap.gz -w output.pcap -O "my lua protocol" -V
```

even when I try -O udp -V I do not get the protocol output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any output if you just run `tshark -X lua_script:my.lua -r input.pcap.gz -Y "myluaprotocol"` to filter the input file for packets that only contain the protocol of interest?  If not, then it would seem there are no packets matching your protocol and thus the protocol details for that protocol can't be expanded using the `-O` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try tshark option `-q` like in
`tshark -X lua_script:RatingGroup.lua -r OneGy_sess_DIAMETER_Dialogue-6_on_06_Jun.pcap  -q`

[image]

As you can see no decoded packets:
[image]